# AWS cloudformation: Unable to delete a stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have created a simple cloudformation

```
Resources:
  MyNewEC2Instance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      ImageId: ami-0b16d80945b1a9c7d
      InstanceType: t2.micro
      SubnetId: subnet-0cc709c048a0ec292
      SecurityGroupIds:
        - sg-09cd08e7081541ada
      KeyName: stg-emr-test
```

The stack was successfully created. I was able to ssh into the ec2 instance. but now i want to remove this stack. i.e the Ec2 instance

and later tried to delete it. Its failing

[image]

I saw the error in events
[image]

Comment: Check the "Events" tab. What do the events say?

Comment: it shows the error there. thanks

Comment: how come i am able to create but not able to delete.

Comment: Hard to say, you haven't shared the error message with us

Comment: I have added the error message in the edit question

Comment: You have added an incomplete screenshot. Add the entire error message as text

Comment: i have added not please check

Comment: The logged in user has the rights to create, but not terminate/delete. Make sure that the correct permissions are assoicated to the user to perform any action within the AWS account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logged in user has the rights to create, but not terminate/delete.

Make sure that the correct permissions (via AWS IAM) are assoicated to the user to perform any action within the AWS account

Answer (score 0):

As assumed above, there is no allow or there is an explicit deny action in a Policy. However, it's clear to me, it's not in IAM if you are asking `how come i am able to create but not able to delete`. Plus, an encoded message, usually, is a sign of AWS Organization being used.

It has to be an SCP applied on your account. Check the [Policy evaluation logic](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_evaluation-logic.html).
Additionally, double-check [Permissions boundaries](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_boundaries.html) and IAM Policy to alleviate any uncertainties or doubts

It's also advisable to decode the error:

```
aws sts decode-authorization-message --encoded-message 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 --query DecodedMessage --output text
```

It may help.

Comment: Please, let me know what it is. And what says the message? Thanks!

Comment: thansk for this insight. unfortunately i dont have permission to decode also